# php code written in html file doesn't work on 1and1 hosting but works on 000webhost

Tags: php, html

OK, so I put together a PHP script that will iterate through a web directory's files and place each file in an HTML5 audio player tag. This way, all one has to do is upload an audio file to the web server, and the script will automatically embed it in an HTML5 audio player.

The problem is that while this script, which is written inside of an HTML document (the page that the audio players will appear on), works perfectly on my 000webhost server, it doesn't on my 1and1 web server.

Here's how the code looks like:

```
--HTML up here...--

<?php
if ($handle = opendir('sermons')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if (($file != ".") && ($file != "..") && ($file != "index.html"))
        {
            $thelist .= '<div class="audio-player">
            <h4>'.$file.'</h4>
            <audio controls>
                <source src="sermons/'.$file.'" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>
            </div>';
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
?>

<?=$thelist?>

--...and down here--
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. I think it might just be the web servers and how they each treat PHP within HTML(maybe). I don't know; all I know is that when I try to view this page from the 1and1 server in Chrome, I get [**THIS**](http://lmccma.org/LMC/audio-sermons.html). When I view it from my 000webhost server in Chrome, I get [**THIS**](http://jpmtech.tk/TEST/LMC/audio-sermons.html) (which is what it's supposed to look like).

I don't know too much about PHP, I just started getting into it, but I am somewhat familiar with it.

Comment: Please use screenshots to show what you get for each.  A link to your page is **very** likely to suffer from link rot.

Comment: Your PHP code isn't being interpreted - it's in a .html file, so the server isn't configured to parse that as PHP; I assume the other host does that. You can rename the file to have a .php extension.

Comment: Your PHP code is showing up in your output, which means your 1&1 host is misconfigured or doesn't have PHP available. Do a 'view source'...

Comment: ALSO, both these sites are currently being hosted in a sub-directory on these hosting servers (as you can see via the URL's). Not sure if that could be causing the problem even though they are both in sub-directories:\

Comment: @andrewsi Thanks for the quick reply:) How do I link the PHP function to the HTML; do I use a form or something to do with "POST" or "GET" ?? Again, still new with PHP.

Comment: I viewed the source for the 1and1 version, and I noticed that everything after and including the `<h4>` tag is not the same color as everything before the `<h4>` tag, which I guess suggests that that part is not being recognized as PHP code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon how your server is configured, you might not be able to call PHP from HTML. To solve this, make one of the changes below to your .HTACCESS file either in the root folder or the folder where the html page is running:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

That directive will enable php in all html pages. If you just want to add it for one particular page, use this directive:

```
<Files index.html> 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</Files>
```

The above assumes that your page is named index.html. Change it to whatever it is.

Comment: I tried both solutions and neither worked:( I could try putting the PHP in a separate .php file as suggested above; I just don't know how to interface it with the HTML.

Comment: That's odd because that should work. It works on my own servers. Do you already have an .htaccess in either root or the directory the file is in?  The quickest solution, other than the one I suggested, is to rename your page to .php. add the html then put php tags around the php cpde.

Comment: I do have an .htaccess, but it's oddly stored in a "logs" folder outside the root, I think

Comment: AHA! Renaming the page to .php worked! Thanks for your help, Len_D:)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    <?
```

instead of

```
    <?php
```

This worked for me on 1and1.